# Converting a list of timestamp into readable format (requiring a quick way)

Tags: python, list, datetime

I can have stored a list of timestamp (in milliseconds) in one column in a dataframe. so i can call them with the following code:

```
dataframename['columnname']
```

gives me something like:

```
0      1512734400000

1      1512738000000

2      1512741600000
```

...

```
498    1514527200000

499    1514530800000
```

I want to convert all of them in to a readable format. I can do it with the following code:

```
for x in range(len(dataframename["columnname"])):
      dataframename['columnname'][x] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dataframename['columnname'][x]/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

However, this is taking too much time. Is there a quicker way of doing it?

Thank you in advance for anyone who is answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
dataframename['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframename['columnname'], unit='ms')
```

See [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) docs for more examples

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly! Also if i want to adjust according to my time zone, i simply need to add a value after dataframe. for example, for GMT+8:                                                                                           dataframename['date']=pd.to_datetime(dataframename['columnname']+3600*1000*8, unit='ms')

Answer (score 0):

Pandas supports timestamp to datetime out-of-the-box:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframename['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframename['columnname'], unit='ms')
```

In case you have multiple columns:

```
# processing the UNIX timestamps into readable dates (pandas datetime):
ts_cols = dataframename.select_dtypes(['datetime']).columns
for col in ts_cols:
    dataframename['%s' % col] = pd.to_datetime(dataframename['%s' % col], unit='ms')
```

---

The performance gain for using the pandas' `to_datetime` over external date -
 [it's 2x faster on small dataset, and it'd scale.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34122697/1384641)